# How to read in a JPG image into a 3 matrices: red, green, blue?

Tags: java, jpeg

What is the process to read in a JPG image into a 3 matrices (intensities): red, green, blue?

Comment: Use an appropriate image processing library.

Comment: [imageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could search for a relevant class in the java api
this might help: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html